# Dart List - filter on sub type

Tags: dart

In my dart projects a construct occurs often in many contexts. For a List with types, that has child types, this code filters out the child types to a new list :

```
class A {
}

class AChild extends A {  
}

List<A> alist = [new A(), new AChild()];
List<AChild> aclist = alist.where((final A a) => a is AChild).
                            map((final A a) => a as AChild).toList();
```

Not a big deal, things works ok. So I just search some polish. Could this be replaced with a function or something more compact? Have tried to write a function with a List and a generic type, but don't get the `is` to accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the tip from Günter, that instead of a function use a tool class. If occurring often the filter class can be put as constant in the project, so nice. Got following:

```
class A {}

class AChild extends A {}

class TypeFilter<T, Z>{

  const TypeFilter();

  List<T> list(List<Z> lz){
    return lz.where((final Z z) => z is T)
        .map((final Z z) => z as T).toList();
  }
}

main(List<String> args) {
  const TypeFilter filterAChild = const TypeFilter<AChild, A>();

  List<A> alist = [new A(), new AChild()];
  List<AChild> aclist = filterAChild.list(alist);
  print(aclist);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you would consider this shorter. If you use this pattern often, it might be:

```
class CheckType<T> {
  bool isT(dynamic v) => v is T;
  
  T as(dynamic v) => v as T;
}

main() {
  final ct = new CheckType<AChild>();
  List<A> alist = [new A(), new AChild()];
  List<AChild> aclist = new List<AChild>.from(alist.where(ct.isT).map(ct.as));
}
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/91ea9bf9ff27d7a552e71e60011ee318)

Comment: Cool twist with the `CheckType` maybe I will use a flavor of this, thanks. Tried to wrap in function, but it stayed with the type of the original list.

Comment: Generic type parameters of functions are not yet available at runtime. AFAIK  this is planned for later.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [whereType<T>](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Iterable/whereType.html) method on iterable types. Just tell the type to `T`.

```dart
void main() {
  const myList = ['a', 'b', 1, 2];
  var onlyInts = myList.whereType<int>().toList();
  print(onlyInts); // [1, 2]
}
```

This also passes the new type to the next chain. So if you go on with:

```
myList.whereType<int>().map((e) => e).toList();
```

`e` here is inferred as `int` type so the compiler will not complain.

Comment: Yes the sdk function whereType is what is needed. At the time of question not available, so the answers presents some small snippets that does the same. But now the whereType should be used instead.

Comment: Just wanted to write this answer because I came while searching so that it helps to the others.