# Dart: typedef with generics seems not to work

Tags: generics, dart, typedef

I would like to define a function through a typedef and then passing the right Type when calling it.
Something like this:

```
typedef testFn<T>();

main() {
  testFn tester;
  tester = testerFn;
  tester<int>(); // Error: The method '() → dynamic' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given.
}

testerFn<T>() {//Do something}
```

I don't know if this a bug or not, but, anyway, how I could I solve something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems familiar with [Dart List - filter on sub type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545593/dart-list-filter-on-sub-type)

So maybe a construct by wrapping with a class could solve your case.

```
typedef testFn<T>();

class TestF<T> {
  final testFn _f;
  const TestF(final testFn this._f);
  eval() => _f();
}

testerFn<T>() {
  print('testFn!');
}

main() {
  TestF<int> c = const TestF(testerFn);
  c.eval();
}
```

---

Actually in the original code, if the function is declared with a `int` specifier it will work.

```
typedef testFn<T>();

main() {
  testFn<int> tester;
  tester = testerFn;
  tester();
}

testerFn<T>(){
  print('testerFn!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas.
I did a little modification:

`typedef testFn<T>(T value);
class TestF<T> {
  final testFn<T> _f;
  const TestF(final testFn<T> this._f);
  eval(T value) => _f(value);
}

testerFn<T>(T value) {
  print('testFn! ${value.toString()}');
}

main() {
  TestF<int> c = const TestF(testerFn);
  c.eval(9);
}
`
My aim was to avoid the possibility of passing a wrong variable to the function. Now, If I change the code to `c.eval('Not OK');` I get an error. So, your solution works!

Comment: Great. This solution is not evident, but I had familiar issue as you see :-) Stackoverflow has a system for marking questions solved. At left hand side of the answer there is checkmark, you can mark if you regard it as solved.

Comment: Jonas, do you think that the problem I wrote is a Dart bug or is it me that is missing something?

Comment: I haven't the total overview, but don't think it is a bug. To me 'tester<int>();` don't look correct. But using 'testFn<int> tester;` in the declaration should work.